# Android: Bitmaps resizing themselves on higher resolution devices

Tags: android, eclipse, bitmap

I'm making a game on Android in Eclipse, and when I run it through the emulator, it appears fine.  The emulator I set up has the resolution at 800x480 (sideways).  When I run the game on my phone, with resolution 1920x1200, it screws up the bitmaps by only drawing a fourth of them.  I've made test code and two screenshots to show what I mean.

Small screen, emulator, running 2.3.3
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WstK.png

Large screen, Galaxy S4, running 4.2.2
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wtAD.png

It's the same code on each.  The top has the dimensions correctly in the emulator (frame size of the bear, which is 64x64), but on the larger resolution it's halved the width and doubled the height for some reason.

The bear at the bottom is set to be near the bottom coordinates whatever the screen size, which is why it's different in each screenshot.  The rectangles and top bear is set from the top coordinates.

I can post code but I'm just wondering if it's some type of setting that I'm unaware of because of the difference in resolution.

One more thing, I have the rectangles flipped horizontally from their original bitmap, so the fact that it appears to have taken the top right part of the bitmap to draw is not part of this, as far as I know.  Again, just wondering if it's some setting that auto-scales things if the resolution is huge.  I have a feeling it's something like that, OR that it's running on such a newer version of Android.  Could be lots of things I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Android usually scales up / scales down the image if it cannot find the right image assets for the device resolution. I believe this could be the reason for the behaviour you are observing. You can read more about providing the proper assets for different device configurations here,
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Alternatively, if you don't want android to scale your images you can also place the image resources under drawable-nodpi folder.